# Angular TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null in Promise subscribe()

Tags: angular

I am calling an API endpoint and receiving an error back but I can not view the error when using console.log because I get error below. Is there another way to get the error?

**ERROR**

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at http.js:109
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HttpHeaders.lazyInit (http.js:103)
    at HttpHeaders.init (http.js:251)
    at HttpHeaders.forEach (http.js:354)
    at Observable._subscribe (http.js:2153)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:172)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:160)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:23)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:132)
```

**PROVIDER**

```js
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Http, Headers , RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class GamesProvider {

    // API url 
    apiUrl = 'http://xxxxx.com/api';

    headers : any;
    options: any;

    this.headers =  new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );

    this.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer' + this.token);

    this.options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers});

    getUsers(ex) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
       this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/api/online/'+ex, {headers: this.options}).subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
       }, err => {
        console.log(err);
       }).catch((err) => {

                // Do messaging and error handling here

                return Observable.throw(err)
            });
     });
    }
```

Comment: Where do you use length? i think you miss the part where you use length property

Comment: I dont use it...

Comment: Is this a function ? Can you show more of your code?

Comment: Yes its the entire code of 1 function

Comment: `return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>` and `reject(err);` inside of your catch or `err=>{ reject(err);}` I am not sure it may give the same result

Comment: Now the error disappears but I need to find out the error because it doesnt return the data from the api endpoint that is why there is an error

Comment: And the endpoint works fine on Postman

Comment: You don't inject http in constructor ? Constructor is missing?

Comment: I have HttpClient , Http is deprecated from >4.3

Comment: It works fine if I dont add headers and dont use authorization on backend

Comment: For this line - this.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer' + this.token) - I cannot see the "token" member.

Comment: Set header only if token is exist!

Answer (score 23):

The cause of this error is that you are adding a header to you http request that has a value of `null`. You aren't doing it in your provided code, so chances are that this happens in your http interceptor.

It could very easily happen if your http interceptor adds a token to *every* http request, even if a value for the token has not been set, or if the interceptor is not properly accessing the token variable.

Comment: Actually true for my issue. Seems like there is currently a problem in `headers.set` as it does not replace the value of the header with the existing key and just works as `headers.append`. Leaving me with two headers with the same keys, one with null value and the second with the newly `set` value.

Answer (score 10):

This happens when any of the value in headers is `null` or `undefined`.

For example:

```
{ headers: this.options }
```

If `this.options` is something like:

```
{ token : null }
```

You will get the error mentioned in this question.
You won't even see a request being generated by angular http in this case.